# Why ViewModel is not providing data when I return to activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, viewmodel

**MainActivity** uses **ViewModel** to display a list of books. When I return back from **DetailActivity** to  **MainActivity**. **MainActivity** does not have the list anymore.

**Why ViewModel is not providing the list when I return to MainActivity?**

**How can I retain the list for MainActivity?**

MainActivity shows a list of books. When user touch list item. It starts **BookDetailActivity** by using below method.

```java
private void startDetailActivity(String id){

        Intent detailActivity = new Intent(this,BookDetailActivity.class);
        detailActivity.putExtra("id",id);
        startActivity(detailActivity);

    }
```

It uses **ViewModel** to get and display book list. **ViewModel** is initialized by this method.

```java
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        bookViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BookViewModel.class);

        //book list live data observer
        bookViewModel.getBookList().observe(this, new Observer<ArrayList<Book>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable ArrayList<Book> books) {
                Log.i("Adapter",""+books.size());
                adapter.clear();
                adapter.setData(books);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


        //status live data observer
        bookViewModel.getStatus().observe(this, new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable Boolean aBoolean) {
                showErrorMessage();
            }
        });

    }
```

**BookDetailActivity**

This activity load book detail from data. It also uses the same **ViewModel** to get and display data. The **ViewModel** is initialized in the **onCreate() method** of **BookDetailActivity**.

```java
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_detail);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Intent data = getIntent();

        String id = data.getStringExtra("id");

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(BookViewModel.class);

        //book detail observer
        viewModel.getBookDetail().observe(this, new Observer<BookDetail>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable BookDetail bookDetail) {
                setDetail(bookDetail);
            }
        });//end of observer

        viewModel.getBookDetail(id);
    }
```

In **Manifest** file, **BookDetailActivity** has **MainActivity** as its parent activity. User can go back to the **MainActivity** by pressing the back button in the top left corner.

**BookViewModel**

**BookViewModel** extends **ViewModel** class. It has three **LiveData objects** for the **book, book detail, and status**. **Book LiveData** is observed by **MainActivity**. It returns a list of book. **Book detail LiveData** is observed by **BookDetailActivity**.  It returns a BookDetail object. Status is observed by both  Activities for network request status.

```java
package com.google.firebase.udacity.findabook.viewmodel;

import android.app.Application;
import android.arch.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel;
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.udacity.findabook.model.BookDetail;
import com.google.firebase.udacity.findabook.repository.BookRepository;
import com.google.firebase.udacity.findabook.model.Book;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BookViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private LiveData<ArrayList<Book>> bookList;
    private LiveData<Boolean> status;
    private LiveData<BookDetail> bookDetail;
    private BookRepository repository;

    public BookViewModel(){
        repository = new BookRepository();
        bookList = repository.getBookList();
        status = repository.getStatus();
        bookDetail = repository.getBookDetail();
    }

    public LiveData<ArrayList<Book>> getBookList(){ return bookList;}

    public LiveData<Boolean> getStatus(){return status;}

    public LiveData<BookDetail> getBookDetail(){return bookDetail;}

    public void searchByBookName(String bookName){
        repository.makeRequestBasedOnBookName(bookName);
    }

    public void getBookDetail(String id){
        repository.getBookDetail(id);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        super.onCleared();
        Log.i("Book view model","Cleared");
    }
}
```

**I have tried--**

**-> Moving the initialization of view model from resume to start method.**

**-> extended viewmodel from AndroidViewModel class**

Comment: Can you post your viewmodel class please

Answer (score 0):

Use the below constructor to set the data in ViewModel with the help of LiveData

```
public BookViewModel(){
        repository = new BookRepository();
        bookList = repository.getBookList();
        status = repository.getStatus();
        bookDetail = repository.getBookDetail();
    }
```

or make the static method in **ViewModel class** to set the data in List with the help of **setVlaue()** method.

also please provide the class from where you are setting data in ViewModel.